# Load a JSON file in local system using jQuery/Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, json

I am new to scripting languages. I have a `new.json` file and I want to load in `gary.html` HTML file. I do not want to run `gary.html` file on server. I want to run it locally on my machine.

When my HTML file loads the `new.json` file using `$.getJSON`, I get a blank screen and when I checked on console I get the error:

> jquery-3.1.0.js:9392 XMLHttpRequest cannot load file:///C:/Users/Gary/Desktop/new.json. Cross origin requests are only supported for protocol schemes: http, data, chrome, chrome-extension, https, chrome-extension-resource.`

and this my loading code

```
function show() {
    //read(a)
    var myItems;

    $.getJSON('new.json', function(data) {
        myItems = data.a;
        read(myItems)
    });
}
```

When I googled for this error, people suggest to me run this file on firefox, or execute this `chrome --allow-file-access-from-files`. The file is loading in firefox and when I am executing the `chrome --allow-file-access-from-files`, the File also loads in chrome.

My main concern is that when I distribute the `new.json` and `gary.html` file to others then others may or may not have firefox or chrome's `chrome --allow-file-access-from-files` permission. I just want user to click on `gary.html` and it loads the data of `new.json` file.

How can I achieve that?

Comment: As you've seen - you can't make AJAX requests to the local filesystem as it's a huge security issue. The only workaround for this is for the user to manually enable settings in their browser (which is not a great idea anyway). If you do not want this then you will have to use a central server for all requests. The alternative is to include the `new.json` file in the page using an extra `<script />` tag

Comment: Then change `new.json` to assign the object to a variable which you can parse and access as you normally would any standard object without the need for the AJAX call

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan, How can I dot that. My json file looks like this: **{"a": [
    {"name":"avc"},
    {"name":"Anna"},
    {"name":"Peter"}]}**

Comment: You can assign the json in a variable in new.json as : `var data = {"a": [ {"name":"avc"}, {"name":"Anna"}, {"name":"Peter"}]}` and you may access `data.a` directly without invoking $.getJSON api

Comment: @CLIX159 I added an answer with an example for you

Comment: @DhananjayaKuppu, Earlier I was doing the same but I was looking for something different. There is no other way to achieve this?

Comment: No, due to the security restrictions.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan, Sorry that was not for you. Mistakenly I have mentioned you instead of Dhananjaya.

Comment: That's ok - he simply gave you an example of the answer I was providing. The answer is the same in any case - you cannot reliably call the local file system through AJAX

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan, Thanks for giving answer. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you've seen - you can't make AJAX requests to the local filesystem as it's a huge security issue. The only workaround for this is for the user to manually enable settings in their browser (which is not a great idea anyway). If you do not want this then you will have to use a central server for all requests.

The alternative is to avoid using AJAX by including the `new.json` file in the page using an extra `<script />` tag. You will also need to assign the object to a variable in the file, something like this:

```
// new.json
var newJson = {"a": [{"name":"avc"}, {"name":"Anna"}, {"name":"Peter"}]}
```

Then in `gary.html`:

```
<head>
    <script src="jquery.js"></script>
    <script src="new.json"></script>
    <script>
        $(function() {
            newJson.a.forEach(function(item) {
                console.log(item.name);
            });
        })
    </script>
</head>
```

Comment: Are yor sure? Can we do in this way?

Answer (score 1):

You can't make AJAX requests to the local filesystem as it's a huge security issue. Why cant you directly include the JSON data in HTML file directly. You wont have to make AJAX call to fetch the JSON.

```
<head>
<script>
var jsonData = '{"a": [{"name":"avc"}, {"name":"Anna"}, {"name":"Peter"}]}';
for(var i=0; i< jsonData.a.length;i++)
{
var item = jsonData.a[i];
console.log(item.name);
}
</script>
</head>
```